# Add JavaScript String with line breaks and tabs to HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this HTML:

```
<p id="element">Waiting for Message</p>
```

And this string from the server using **JSON.stringify()** with breaks and tabs in it i.e

```
var = "Heading (info:info) \n info: \n \t and so on "; // The actual string is more complex though, just an example
```

And this Jquery to post the string to the paragraph tag:

```
$("#element").text(data); // data is the string from the server(not in JSON!)
```

The problem is the HTML ignores the formatting but when I use an alert box it displays with the proper formatting. I am dynamically updating the element as data comes from the server. Any pointers?

Comment: Use pre instead of p tag.

Comment: You can enclose it in a <pre> tag or change the line breaks to <br /> to have line breaks in HTML.

Comment: Are there any libraries to create a treeview  based on a long string that contains new lines and tabs ? @KRichardson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the `pre tag` in HTML and update your text there

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var data = {
    "id": "1",
    "nome": "erwrw",
    "cognome": "sdsfdfs",
    "CF": "qwert",
    "eta": "27",
    "sesso": "uomo",
    "indirizzo": "qwerrt",
    "luogo": "wewrw",
    "provincia": "ewrewrw",
    "citta": "erwrwr",
    "comune": "ewrewrw"
  }

var obj = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
$('#element').text(obj);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="element">Waiting for Message</pre>
<button id="btn">send</button>
```

Answer (score 9):

You should tell browser to respect those whitepaces. Easy way to do it is using [white-space: pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) rule:

```js
var data = "Heading (info:info) \n info: \n \t and so on "; 

$("#element").html(data);
```

```css
#element {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="element">Waiting for Message</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#element").html(data.replace(/(\n)/g, '<br>'));
```